# Large Deviation Bounds for Number of Forests (or Tutte polynomial) in G(n,p)

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, large-deviation-theory

Does anyone know of results/references related to large deviation bounds on the number of forests (or the Tutte polynomial) in $G(n,p)$ (Erdos-Renyi random graphs)?